# How to set vtk text to "real" Arial?

Tags: text, fonts, vtk, paraview

I am new to VTK and try to set Arial font for a text. The final rendered text is not Arial; rather, it is only some kind of font close to Arial. Could anyone tell how to correctly set Arial font in VTK?

The code to set the font:

```
    legendAxis->GetLabelTextProperty()->SetFontFamilyToArial();
```

I found the same problem in ParaView, where the default font is Arial, but the rendered font is only a font close to Arial (and some kind of not good-looking).

Comment: We're tracking the issue fo ParaView at https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/18144. You can load arbitrary font files with

vtkTextProperty::SetFontFamily(VTK_FONT_FILE)
vtkTextProperty::SetFontFile(const char*)

and point the font file to an arbitrary FreeType-compatible font. You could use this to point to another Arial font file.

Comment: Hi, Cory, thanks for the reply. But even I use a custom ttf file, the rendering is still not correct. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

I have never been able to get `vtkAxisActor` to respond correctly to `SetFontFamily` as you have done.

Instead, try:

```
legendAxis->SetUseTextActor3D(1)    
legendAxis->GetLabelTextProperty()->SetFontFile("C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf");
```

To point it directly at the Arial font file available for your system.  Of course, you'll have to tweak the path to fit your specific OS/platform.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, Joshua, thanks but I am using vtkAxisActor2D, instead of AxisActor, therefore I cannot find SetUseTextActor3D property.

Comment: Kai, I've only had experience with `vtkAxisActor` on this issue and can't speak to how to correct it with `vtkAxisActor2D`.  Sorry...